# How do I access an enum from another class in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have the following example:

```
class ClassOne {
    enum Color {
        case Red
        case Blue
    }

    func giveColor() -> Color {
        return .Red
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    let classOne = ClassOne()
    var color: Color = classOne.giveColor()
}
```

The compiler complains that it doesn't know what `Color` is in `ClassTwo`. How would I best handle this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `Color` enumeration is a *nested type* -- you'll access it as `ClassOne.Color`. Moreover, you can't assign one property from another in the declaration like that. Leave it unassigned and do it in the `init()`:

```
class ClassOne {
    enum Color {
        case Red
        case Blue
    }

    func giveColor() -> Color {
        return .Red
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    let classOne = ClassOne()
    var color: ClassOne.Color

    init() {
        self.color = self.classOne.giveColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the default value of one property in the default value of another. You can fix this by setting color in the init method:

```
class ClassTwo {
    let classOne: ClassOne = ClassOne()
    var color: ClassOne.Color
    init(){
        color = classOne.giveColor()
    }
}
```

Since Color is an enum inside of ClassOne, for its type you should use `ClassOne.Color` instead of `Color`.

You could also make color a computed property like this:

```
class ClassTwo {
    let classOne: ClassOne = ClassOne()
    var color: ClassOne.Color {
    get{
        return classOne.giveColor()
    } }
}
```

In the first example `color` is set as `classOne.giveColor()` only when it is initialized, but in the second example `classOne.giveColor()` is called everytime you try to access `color`.

Comment: You can omit the 'get' block if there is no setter. var color: ClassOne.Color { return classOne.giveColor(); }